# Use flexbox to adapt image height

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a layout with two rows. The lower row contains images and those should adapt to the available height.

The thing is, that the images change their height, but the width acts weird. Even when I set `height: 100%` and `width: auto`.

I made a simplified Pen for that: https://codepen.io/oliverspies/pen/zaeVRw

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bottom {
  flex: 0 2 25rem;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 25rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.bottom img {
  height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="top">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/600?random">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random">
  </div>
</div>
```

So what I want to achieve finally is that the images are 400px high, unless the available height is less, then the images should shrink, but the aspect ratio should stay intact. I think the problem only occurs, when the window is resized so that the images have less than 400px height.

Comment: set `max-height:100%; max-width:100%` on those images

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa I'm afraid this doesn't help anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove the flexbox from the images and just let them be inline as the are by default and use max-height: 100%:

```css
.flexContainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
}

.bottom{
  flex: 0 2 25rem;
  height: 100%;
  max-height: 25rem;
}

.bottom img{  
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-right: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="top">
    Content
  </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/g/600?random">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but then the images aren't aligned on the left.

Comment: Actually the images are aligned to the left, you just have large margin-right on the images

Comment: I need the margin between the images not to change. So I guess this isn't achievable with object fit.

Comment: @obs Then I don't understand what is it that you want, the images can't both be "on the left" and have large margin-right...

Comment: I dont't want "large margin-right". The thing with object fit is, that the image-container stays the same size, but the image itself adapts. But then the distance to the next image doesn't change. You can leave the margin between the images - than I want that all the images are always touch eachother and there is no free space where the background comes through.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.flexContainer{
    display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
}
 ul{
    list-style: none;
     column-count: 3;
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
}
 .top{
    background: red;
     color: white;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     padding: 1em;
     padding-bottom: 1em;
     padding-bottom: 2em;
     flex: 2 0 auto;
}
 .bottom{
     background: blue;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: space-between;
}
 .bottom > div:nth-child(2){
    margin: 0 1rem;
}
 .bottom img{
     max-width: 100%; vertical-align: top; 
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
    <div class="top">
        <ul>
            <li>one</li>
            <li>two</li>
            <li>three</li>
            <li>four</li>
            <li>five</li>
            <li>six</li>
            <li>seven</li>
            <li>eight</li>
            <li>nine</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/g/600?random"></div>
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/600"></div>
        <div><img src="https://picsum.photos/600?random"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hope you checked my code snippet, could you please send the updated snippet with the disappear issue? because there is no element is showing below the image, what is disappears in bottom?

Comment: when I click "run code snippet" I only see the red background, not the blue one. It's the same when I apply your code to my pen.

Comment: please review the recordit video for your reference.
http://recordit.co/h76uJwcuWq

Comment: thanks for your effort - here is how it looks for me: http://recordit.co/nHkkvQGlJ0

Comment: Hi, i have updated the code, could you please **Run my above code snippet**!

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap each IMG with a div.
Then set the div height to 400px
and the img max-height to 100%

.img-wrapper{
height:400px
}

.img-wrapper img{
max-height:100%
}

Comment: When I try this, the images don't get smaller, when the available height for the images is less than 400px.